# What is the difference between pronounciation of alphabets श and ष in mantras

Tags: vedas, mantras, vedic-rituals, gayatri-mantra, manuscripts

There are many mantras with the above two alphabets. Obviously both of them cannot have the same sound. What is the exact difference in their pronounciation. Official references are welcome.

Comment: This is basic Sanskrit alphabet. There are many references for which sound should come from [where](https://delightyoga.com/uploads/inspiration/99bc3da552e93480ae469f8b31a2353a9f8695b7.large@2x.png). Basically for ष tongue touches deeper in top of mouth, whereas for श it touches closer to teeth